# Is every $T_3$ pseudocompact P-space finite?

Tags: general-topology

I think the following result should be true:

> Every $T_3$ pseudocompact P-space is finite and discrete.

Here a space $X$ is:

- $T_3$ if it is regular Hausdorff,
- *pseudocompact* if every real-valued continuous function on $X$ is bounded,
- a *P-space* if countable intersections of open sets are open.

Can anyone provide a proof?

Comment: Sounds like a fun question. Do you have some intuition that motivates this conjecture? Maybe we can turn your insights into a proof.

Comment: This is exercise 4K.2 in Gillman-Jerison. The first part of the exercise asks to show that every countable subset of a P-space is C-embedded, from which the conclusion follows without much difficulty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more elementary proof, I think.

We'll need a preliminary result.

> **[Lemma](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000351)**: Every regular P-space is zero dimensional.

*Proof of lemma* (for completeness, see the link):  Let $x$ be a point of $X$ and let $U_0$ be an open nbhd of $x$.  By regularity, each nbhd of a point contains a closed nbhd of the point.  So we can construct a descending sequence of open nbhds $U_n$ of $x$ such that
$$U_0\supseteq\overline{U_1}\supseteq U_1\supseteq\overline{U_2}\supseteq U_2\supseteq\cdots.$$

The intersection of all those is
$U=\bigcap_{n<\omega}U_n=\bigcap_{n<\omega}\overline{U_n},$
which is closed (as an intersection of closed sets) and open (as a countable intersection of open sets).  So $U$ is a clopen nbhd of $x$ contained in $U_1$.

---

*Proof of main result*: Let $X$ be a $T_3$ pseudocompact P-space.  To show it is finite, it is enough to show the space is discrete, as an infinite discrete space is clearly not pseudocompact.

Suppose by contradiction that $X$ is not discrete.  There is a point $p\in X$ such that the singleton $\{p\}$ is not open, that is, every nbhd of $p$ contains another point.  Also, because $X$ is $T_1$, every nbhd of $p$ contains a strictly smaller nbhd.  Combining this with the lemma, every nbhd of $p$ contains a strictly smaller clopen nbhd.

Now take $U_0=X$ and construct a strictly descending sequence of clopen nbhds of $p$:
$$U_0\supsetneq U_1\supsetneq U_2\supsetneq\cdots.$$
Their intersection $U=\bigcap_{n<\omega}U_n$ is closed (as an intersection of closed sets) and open (using the P-space property).  The collection $\{U_n\setminus U_{n+1}:n<\omega\} \cup \{U\}$ is a partition of $X$ into an countably infinite number of nonempty clopen sets.  Any function that is constant on each member of the partition is continuous.  So there are unbounded continuous functions $f:X\to\mathbb R$, contradicting pseudocompactness.

Answer (score 3):

Some observations and a partial answer assuming normal in place of regular:

Every countable subset of a $T_1$ P-space is closed and discrete: points are closed by $T_1$, and countable unions of closed are closed by P-space.

Every regular P-space is completely regular: see https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000351 and https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000054

Every $T_4$ pseudocompact P-space is finite: [closed subsets of normal pseudocompacts are pseudocompact](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3772407), so every countable subset is discrete and pseudocompact, and therefore finite. Thus the space has no infinite subsets.

Comment: Useful observations.  For a $T_1$ P-space, every countable set is closed.  So does that mean that every set in $X$ is sequentially closed (and sequentially open)?  I.e., the space is "sequentially discrete", if there is such a thing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that's true.

Let $X$ be a topological space.
We need the following well-known defintions:

1. $X$ is *pseudonormal*, if two disjoint, closed sets, one of which is countable, can be separated by disjoint open sets.
2. $X$ has *property D*, if for every discrete, closed, countable subset $D$ there is a discrete, open collection $(U_x)_{x \in D}$ such that $x \in U_x$ for all $x\in D$.

See for instance [here](https://webpages.charlotte.edu/%7Eadow/pseudoT4.pdf). There it is also mentioned that it is easy to see that pseudonormal spaces have property D, which we will take as granted.
(The original statement of this paper assumes T2. However, this is not necessary. Anyway, this is irrelevant here, since the question is in T2 context.)

Since in a pseudocompact, completely regular T2 space every discrete open collection is finite, pseudocompact, completely regular, pseudonormal T2 spaces are countably compact (= closed, discrete subsets are finite). Obviously, countably compact T1 P-spaces are finite (see Steven Clontz' answer).

So, it remains to show that T3 P-spaces are pseudonormal:

Let $A, B$ be disjoint, closed subsets of $X$, $A$ countable. Since a T3 P-space is zero-dimensional, for each $a \in A$ there is a clopen $U_a$ such that $a \in U_a \subset X \setminus B$.
Then $U := \bigcup_{a \in A} U_a$ is clopen,  $A \subset U \subset X \setminus B$.

Comment: For the record, regular P-spaces are zero dimensional, even without Hausdorff (see [here](https://topology.pi-base.org/theorems/T000351)).  So the last paragraph also shows that regular P-spaces are pseudonormal.

Answer (score 3):

This is a perspective using some more advanced tools, like ring of continuous functions and Stone-Cech compactification.

Let $M_p = \{f : f(p) = 0\}, O_p = \{f : p\in \text{int } f^{-1}(0)\}$, $Z(f) = \{x : f(x) = 0\}$ for $f\in C(X)$. We call an ideal $I\subseteq C(X)$ a $z$-ideal if $Z(f)\subseteq Z(g)$ and $f\in I$ implies $g\in I$. A zero set is a set of the form $Z(f)$.

The following are well-known to be equivalent for a Tychonoff space

1. All prime ideals of $C(X)$ are maximal.
2. $M_p = O_p$ for all $p\in X$.
3. Every zero set $Z\subseteq X$ is open.
4. Every $G_\delta$ subset of $X$ is open.
5. Every ideal in $C(X)$ is a $z$-ideal.
6. Every ideal in $C(X)$ is an intersection of prime ideals.
7. For $f, g\in C(X)$, $(f, g) = (f^2+g^2)$.
8. For $f\in C(X)$, $(f^2) = (f)$.
9. Every ideal in $C(X)$ is an intersection of maximal ideals.

For completion I'll give a proof of all equivalences.

$(1\implies 2)$ $O_p$ is a $z$-ideal and every $z$-ideal is semi-prime i.e. it's intersection of prime ideals (see theorem 2.8 in Gillman and Jerison). So $O_p = M_p$.

$(2\implies 3)$ If $Z = Z(f)$ is a zero set then $f\in M_p = O_p$ for all $p\in Z$. That is, $\text{int } Z = Z$ i.e. $Z$ is open.

$(3\implies 4)$ If $x\in U = \bigcap_n U_n$ where $U_n$ are open, take $f_n:X\to [0, 1]$ such that $f_n(x) = 0$ and $f_n$ equals $1$ on $U_n^c$. Then $f = \sum_n 2^{-n} f_n$ is continuous, $f(x) = 0$ and $Z(f)\subseteq U$. Thus $U$ is open.

$(4\implies 5)$ If $I$ is an ideal, $Z(f)\subseteq Z(g)$, $f\in I$ then define $h(x) = g(x)/f(x)$ for $x\notin Z(f)$ and $h(x) = 0$ for $x\in Z(f)$. Since $Z(f)$ is a clopen set (it's a closed $G_\delta$), $h$ is continuous and $g = fh$. Since $I$ is an ideal, $g\in I$.

$(5\implies 6)$ Every ideal is a $z$-ideal, so semi-prime. This is theorem 2.8 of Gillman and Jerison as I mentioned earlier.

$(5\implies 7)$ Clearly $f^2+g^2\in (f, g)$ and since $Z(f^2+g^2) = Z(f)\cap Z(g)$ and $(f^2+g^2)$ is a $z$-ideal, we have $f, g\in (f^2+g^2)$.

$(6\implies 8)$ If $P$ is a prime ideal then $f\in P$ iff $f^2\in P$, so $(f) = (f^2)$.

$(7\implies 8)$ Set $f = g$ or $g = 0$.

$(8\implies 1)$ Let $P\subseteq C(X)$ be prime, $f\notin P$ and $f = f^2f_0$, then $f(1-ff_0) = 0\in P$ so that $1-ff_0\in P$. In other words, every non-zero element of $C(X)/P$ is invertible, so $C(X)/P$ is a field. Thus $P$ is maximal.

$(1\text{ and } 6 \implies 9)$ and $(9\implies 6)$ Obvious.

This means that for Tychonoff spaces the property "$X$ is a P-space" is purely algebraic, and depends only on the ring $C(X)$.

If $X$ is a pseudocompact Tychonoff P-space (note that $T_3$ P-space is zero-dimensional, so Tychonoff), then $C(X) = C(\beta X)$ where $\beta X$ is the Stone-Cech compactifiaction of $X$. Now it suffices to show that compact P-spaces are finite.

Indeed, if $\beta X$ were infinite, then it'd contain an infinite subspace $\{x_1, x_2, ...\}\subseteq X$, and the family $\{\{x_n, x_{n+1}, ...\} : n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ would consist of closed sets, have finite intersection property, but its intersection is empty. This contradicts that $\beta X$ is compact. Since $\beta X$ is finite, so is $X$.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand one part of it.  The definition of P-space corresponds to condition (5) above.  And various other conditions are purely described in terms of the ring structure of $C(X)$.  Now $C(X)$ and $C(\beta X)$ are isomorphic as rings: that would not be true for general Tychonoff spaces, but requires pseudocompact also?   And therefore $C(\beta X)$ satisfies the same algebraic conditions, and therefore $\beta X$ is a P-space.

Comment: @PatrickR not all conditions above are purely in terms of $C(X)$ e.g. the property of being a $z$-ideal is not an algebraic property. Bounded continuous functions on $X$ and $\beta X$ are ring isomorphic. This holds for any Tychonoff space. Pseudocompactness allows us to say all continuous functions on $X$ are bounded.

Comment: Yeah, I mistyped, the definition of P-space is condition (4).  Thanks for the clarifications.