# Why do pseudonormal spaces have property D?

Tags: general-topology

In [https://webpages.charlotte.edu/~adow/pseudoT4.pdf](https://webpages.charlotte.edu/%7Eadow/pseudoT4.pdf) Dow asserts "It is easy to see that every Hausdorff pseudonormal (hence regular) space will have property D." Why is that?

We can show $T_1$ pseudonormal spaces are regular. Given a point $x\not\in H$ closed, note that by $T_1$ $\{x\}$ is a countable closed set, so by pseudonormality there is an open set $V\supseteq\{x\}$ with $cl(V)\cap H=\emptyset$.

Here is how I'd attempt to show pseudonormal spaces have property D (which I believe holds whether or not they are $T_1$). Let $D=\{x_n:n<\omega\}$ be closed and discrete. Then each $\{x_n\}$ is closed (even when the space fails to be $T_1$, since $D$ is closed and discrete), as is each $D_n=\{x_N:n<N<\omega\}$. By pseduonormality, we may first obtain an open set $U_n$ with $x_n\in U_n\subseteq cl(U_n)\subseteq X\setminus D_n$. Applying it again, we then obtain an open set $V_n$ with $x_n\in V_n\subseteq cl(V_n) \subseteq U_n$.

We claim $\{W_n:n<\omega\}$ with $W_n=V_n\setminus\bigcup_{m<n}cl(U_m)$ witnesses the $D$-space property. First observe $x_n\in W_n$. Then observe that for $m<n$, $W_n\subseteq X\setminus cl(U_m)\subseteq X\setminus U_m$, and so $cl(W_n)\subseteq X\setminus U_m\subseteq X\setminus cl(V_m)\subseteq X\setminus cl(W_m)$, showing $\{W_n:n<\omega\}$ is pairwise disjoint.

Are these $W_n$ locally finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744697/is-every-t-3-pseudocompact-p-space-finite/4744732#4744732), Hausdorff is not needed
(but I admit, the proof might not be as easy, as I first thought):

Let $X$ be a topological space.

It is convenient to introduce *property E* $:\Leftrightarrow$ for each $x \in X$ and $A \subset X$ such that $\{x\}$ is closed, $x \notin A$ and $A$ is countable, closed, discrete, $\{x\}$ and $A$ can be separated by open, disjoint sets.

Of course, pseudonormality implies property E.

**Lemma.** Let $X$ have property E. If $D$ is a closed, discrete and countable subset of $X$, then there exists a pairwise disjoint, open collection $(U_x)_{x \in D}$ such that $x \in U_x$ for all $x \in D$.

PROOF.
There is a well-order $\le$ on $D$ such that
$D^{<x} := \{y \in D: y < x\}$ is finite for all $x \in D$.
(This clumsy formulation is only chosen to do the finite and infinite case simultaneously.) 
By property E, for each $x \in D$ choose disjoint, open $W_x, V_x$ such that $x \in W_x$ and $D \setminus \{x\} \subset V_x$. 
Then $ (W_x \cap \bigcap_{y \in D^{<x}} V_y)_{x \in D}$ is as required.

Now we can prove that pseudonormal spaces have property D:

Let $D \subset X$ be countable, closed, discrete. By the lemma, there is a pairwise disjoint, open collection
$(U_x)_{x \in D}$ such that $x \in U_x$ for all $x \in D$.
Then
$D \cap (X \setminus \bigcup_{x \in D} U_x) = \emptyset$ and
$X \setminus \bigcup_{x \in D} U_x$ is closed.
Hence there exist open disjoint $U, V$ such that $D \subset U$ and
$X \setminus \bigcup_{x \in D} U_x \subset V$.
Then $(U_x \cap U)_{x \in D}$ is discrete.  
[Let $z \in X$. 
Case 1: $z \in U_{x_0}$ for some $x_0 \in D$.
Then $\{x \in D: U_{x_0} \cap  (U_x \cap U) \neq \emptyset\} = \{x_0\}$.

Case 2: "else": Then $V$ is an open neighborhood of $z$ and
$\{x \in D: V \cap  (U_x \cap U) \neq \emptyset\} = \emptyset$.]

Comment: @Steven Clontz: if anything is unclear with the proof, please let me know.

Comment: Looks good, I was just busy at the MAA meeting the week you posted this. The main issue with my original approach was picking each $V_n$ individually, which may allow $\bigcup_{n<\omega} cl(V_n)$ to not be closed. By using psuedonormality for the entire $D$ as you did instead, I'd get a single $V$ with $cl(V)$ closed, and could proceed with $V_n=U_n\cap V$.